# Unable to start the daemon process -react native, app not installing

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8082

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
  Process command line: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin\java.exe -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Nagaraj.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.9-all\dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs\gradle-6.9\lib\gradle-launcher-6.9.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.9
  Please read the following process output to find out more:

---

Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: have you solved the problem? i have the same problem now, if you have solved it can you tell me?

Comment: my file is an old package file so in gradle.propeties it has -XX:MaxPermSize=512m, 
new version of react native gradle.properties come with -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m, 

you can change the -XX:MaxPermSize=512m to -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m 
or 
remove the line -XX:MaxPermSize=512m please try this, if it won't works for you, please notify me

Comment: Thank you, I remove -XX:MaxPermSize=512m yesterday, and it's work now

Comment: okay super, sorry for the late reply